# javascript indexOf check in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexof

Having some difficulty getting this code to work. Essentially, I want to check if the referring url is coming from the /mobile directory and if not and the screen is a mobile device I want to redirect to the mobile site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href.indexOf("document.write(document.referrer)") > -1 &&
    screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "/mobile/mobile_home.asp";
}

</script>
```

The code is currently placed in the head of the main home.asp.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf('/mobile') > -1 && screen.width < 700) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't want `document.write` here (or virtually anywhere):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf(document.referrer) > -1 &&
    screen.width <= 699) {
```

But your code and your question don't quite match, you've said

> ...if the referring url is coming from the /mobile directory...

That would be something more like

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf("/mobile") > -1 &&
    screen.width <= 699) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifically addressing the indexOf check, 'does not equal' will also work and IMHO makes the intent a bit clearer.

```
if ( a.indexOf(somestring) !== -1 ) {
```

Applied to an example above

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf('/mobile') !== -1
```